# spring cloud bus rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud

We're using spring cloud config server. Spring config clients get updates using spring control bus (RabbitMQ).

Looks like every config client instance creates a queue connected to the 'spring.cloud.bus' exchange.

Any scalability limits on how many app instances can connect to a 'spring.cloud.bus' exchange ?

I suppose RabbitMQ could be scaled to handle this.

Looking for any guidelines on this.

Many thanx,

Answer (score 0):

The spring cloud config server can have multiple instances since it is stateless.  That coupled with a RabbitMQ cluster should scale to a very large number of instances.

A viable solution would be spring cloud config behind a load balancer with a RabbitMQ cluster.